# How do I change my RAID configuration(mdadm)

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I would like to change my current partitioning and RAID configuration without reinstalling Ubuntu 15.04. Here is the output of sudo fdisk -l:
[image: My disk layout]
md0 is /home and md1 is /tmp

I would like to change it so /tmp(md1) can be back with the root partition and md0 can take 40GB on /dev/sdb, with swap taking the other 40GB. I would like the other half(another 40GB) being on /dev/sda. Then I just want /dev/sda3 and /dev/sda4's sizes to stay the same.

I have my Ubuntu root partition on /dev/sda3 and Arch on /dev/sda4.

I just don't want to have to reinstall everything!

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to edit partitions is to use [GParted](http://gparted.org/) tool. I used it to resize partitions on my laptop and it worked great, no data loss at all. Although, to do it, you need the partitions you are working with to be inactive, so you need to make a live CD/USB with GParted. The instructions are given on their website [here](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). Then, you should be able to boot from it and do what you need to do.

Even though there is no 100% guarantee of the safety of the data (please, don't forget to back up all the important files you have),the chance of any loss is almost nonexistent.

Comment: The difficult part is the RAID. How would I manage that?

I know how to use GParted :P